# XNA minimap for randomly generated level

Tags: c#, xna

[Here's the entire code (the problem is at the end if you don't reach the line automatically)](https://gist.github.com/Mranth0ny62/2c73025acadf75721492#file-minimap-L288)

I'm working on a top down rogue like game and the levels are randomly generated but I'm having a problem: I can't seem to get a minimap going

here's the code:

```
        for (y = 0; y <= 19; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x <= 19; x++)
            {
                if (level[x, y] != null)
                {
                    Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
            }
            x = 0;
        }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Resources.room_minimap, new Rectangle(30, 20, 30, 20), null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
```

right now, I'm trying to make it so that the program calls Draw if there's a room in the array level[x, y] but "spriteBatch" doesn't exist in LevelGen so I'm wondering if you guys know if there is a way around that

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LevelGen` class shouldn't handle rendering of the minimap, perhaps your game or level class.

Move your `level` variable out of the method and into the class. Make sure it is public so other classes can access it.

```
public class LevelGen
{
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    public Room[,] level = new Room[x, y];
    //...
```

In your `protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)` method in your `Game` class, move the rendering code there. You need to draw the minimap EVERY FRAME, and not once during world generation.

With your minimap code moved, your Game1.cs (or similar) Draw code should look like:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    for (y = 0; y <= 19; y++)
        for (x = 0; x <= 19; x++)
            if (Map.level[x, y] != null)
                spriteBatch.Draw(Resources.room_minimap, new Rectangle(30, 20, 30, 20), null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
```

Note that `Map.level` needs to be set to your map variable.

Comment: nothing is getting drawn, here's the updated code: https://gist.github.com/Mranth0ny62/7d1576830d888adef9e3

Comment: Little error: Your rectangle is the same for every object, did you mean to do: `new Rectangle(30 * x, 20 * y, 30, 20)`? Also, put a breakpoint (google it if you don't know how) on the `spriteBatch.Draw()` line to make sure it is being hit (Maybe `level[x,y]` really is null?) **EDIT:** It also looks like you are calling `Map()` every update, is that intended?

Comment: >did you mean to do: new Rectangle(30 * x, 20 * y, 30, 20)?
yeah, I forgot about that

>It also looks like you are calling Map() every update, is that intended?

I want to be sure it creates a minimap everytime a level is created, I'm going to change that once I finish the minimap

Comment: Yeah, so they don't draw in one place, although I suppose you would see at least ONE tile if that were the case.

Comment: I hit enter to go to the next line and I posted the comment, damnit!

Comment: Well, try putting a breakpoint on the draw code and make sure it is called.

Comment: I think it has something to do with 'LevelGen levelgen = new LevelGen();' because level[x, y] is entirely null

Comment: Maybe, but you need to confirm with a breakpoint first if draw is even being called.

Comment: Is `spriteBatch.Draw(Resources...` being called?

Comment: no because the entire array is null (the level gets generated and then it gets cleared)

Comment: Your `levelGen` in MacksDream.cs is NOT the same LevelGen as the one with the rooms. You created a separate instance. Move `LevelGen levelgen = new LevelGen();` out of Map() and into the class like you did for `Room[,] Level`, and in your draw code, access L`evelGen.levelgen[...]` instead. Make sure your level variable is `public static` once you move it out.

Answer (score 1):

Im my game i use this code on the update method:

```
Game1.graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(miniMapDrawRenderTarget2D);
Game1.graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

Game1.spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, new BlendState
{
    ColorSourceBlend = Blend.One,
    ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
    AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One,
    AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha
});

if (miniMapTexture2d != null)
{
    sourceRectangle.X = (int)(((Game1.mission.player.position.X - Config.chunkSize * playerRegion.X) / Config.tileSize) + (Config.tilesPerChunk * 0.5f));
    sourceRectangle.Y = (int)((-(Game1.mission.player.position.Y - Config.chunkSize * playerRegion.Y) / Config.tileSize) + (Config.tilesPerChunk * 1.5f));
    Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(miniMapTexture2d, new Rectangle(4, 4, 192, 192), sourceRectangle, Color.White);
}

Game1.mission.textures2D["miniMapMask"].drawOnScreen();

Game1.spriteBatch.End();

Game1.graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
Game1.graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = Game1.display.centerViewport.Bounds;
Game1.graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport = Game1.display.centerViewport;
```

and then on the draw method:

```
Game1.spriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)miniMapDrawRenderTarget2D, new Vector2(800, 0), Color.White);
```